# На что ругается google colab при импорте папки с файлами с гугл диска

Tags: python

Я загружаю файл с гугл диска, в папке Dataset лежат изображения.

```
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
    root_path = 'gdrive/Colab Notebooks/Dataset/'
```

Ошибка:

```
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py in _input_request(self, prompt, ident, parent, password)
    728             try:
--> 729                 ident, reply = self.session.recv(self.stdin_socket, 0)
    730             except Exception:

6 frames
zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv()

zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.recv()

zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx in zmq.backend.cython.socket._recv_copy()

KeyboardInterrupt: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py in _input_request(self, prompt, ident, parent, password)
    732             except KeyboardInterrupt:
    733                 # re-raise KeyboardInterrupt, to truncate traceback
--> 734                 raise KeyboardInterrupt
    735             else:
    736                 break
```

Comment: Вообще такая ошибка, по идее, возникает, когда Вы нажимаете Ctrl+C в терминале при выполнении программы. Возможно есть ещё какие-то случаи, когда это происходит, но я таковых не встречал.

Comment: По идее в этом месте он должен вам предложить ввести authorization code, который можно получить, перейдя по ссылке, которую он даёт. Если вы вместо чтобы ввести код сделаете останов выполнения скрипта каким-либо образом, то будет эта ошибка.